# Magento2: how to override Component.extend property?

Tags: magento2

We noticed that on luma template, validation of email has delayed of 2 seconds. We want to override it so it doesn't have any delay upon email field changed. Is this possible to override?

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/form/element/email',
        email: checkoutData.getInputFieldEmailValue(),
        emailFocused: false,
        isLoading: false,
        isPasswordVisible: false,
        listens: {
            email: 'emailHasChanged',
            emailFocused: 'validateEmail'
        }
    },
    checkDelay: 2000,
    ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done by using mixin, and overriding js using `requirejs-config.js`

Add this to the file `requirejs-config.js` file which is added in `view/frontend` of your module/theme

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email': {
                'Your_Module/custom': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `custom.js` file

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            checkDelay: 1000,
        });
    }
});
```

Another way is you can simply override the js file, by placing the email.js file at this location of your theme -

```
Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/js/view/form/element/email.js
```

Comment: Glad could help :)

Comment: `frontend` is not required in `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/js/view/form/element/email.js`